# Under what circumstances $\langle g^m \rangle = \langle g^n \rangle$ implies $g^m = g^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group, and $g\in G$. Assume that $$\langle g^m \rangle = \langle g^n \rangle$$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> - When can we deduce that $g^m = g^n$?
> - What if $G$ is cyclic? Finite? Cyclic and finite?

For an aribtrary group $G$ and an element $g$ of a finite order $|g|$ we have:

$\langle g^m \rangle = \langle g^n \rangle \Rightarrow g^m \in \langle g^n \rangle$ and $g^n \in \langle g^m \rangle \Rightarrow \exists q, r \in \mathbb{Z}: \ \ n \equiv qm \mod |g|$ and $rn \equiv m \mod |g|$.

If $|g| = \infty$, then $m|n$ and $n|m$, and $m = n$, so, obviously, $g^m = g^n$.

But what if $|g| \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/310315/8581)

Comment: In general, $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$ iff $b=a^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(k,|a|)=1$.

Comment: @BabakS. I see, I've made a mistake. If $|g| = \infty$, and $m|n$ and $n|m$, it's either $m = n$ or $m = -n$.

Answer (score 1):

I take the question to be:

> What is the condition on $g$ so that the following holds:
>   For all $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ we have $\langle g^m\rangle = \langle g^n\rangle \implies g^m = g^n$.

Given that $\langle g\rangle = \langle g^{-1}\rangle$, this obviously implies that $g=g^{-1}$.On the other hand, if $g=g^{-1}$, then $g^n\in\{e,g\}$, and clearly, $\langle e\rangle=\langle g\rangle$ if and only if $e=g$. Therefore the reverse direction also holds, and therefore the answer is:

> The condition holds if and only if $g=g^{-1}$. That is, $g$ is either the neutral element, or an element of order $2$.

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't it always $\langle g \rangle = \langle g^{-1} \rangle$? Besides, the question is not about **all** $m,n$ but some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Say, we have $\langle g^m \rangle = \langle g^n \rangle$ for **some** $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. When can we deduce $g^m = g^n$?

Comment: "Excuse me, but isn't it always $⟨g⟩=⟨g^{−1}⟩$?" Yes, that's exactly what I wrote. — "Besides, the question is not about all m,n but some m,n∈Z." Then I didn't understand the question correctly (and now don't understand it at all). Can you please clarify?